# C# treeview node

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview1:

```
             treenode--
                  treenode1--
                     treenode2
                     treenode3
```

You can select only node2 and node3 if you want to display them parameters. How can i block selecting node and node1? I try like that,but than you can select all nodes:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
    ...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use [SelectAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.selectaction%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Property on the tree node. you will need to set it on the node when you are creating them.

set selectaction=none on node and node1

Comment: does not matter, on nodes you do not want select set Selectaction as none

Comment: But there isn't any "Selectaction"

Comment: what do you mean by there is n select action. <asp:TreeNode Text="node" 
            SelectAction="None"/> and in codebehind you can use 
Node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;

Comment: Sorry, i was meaning treenode, not node. When i want to write: 'SelectAction' i can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a win forms TreeView handle the BeforeSelect event and set the Cancel property of your TreeViewCancelEventArgs parameter to false. For web controls see Vinay's answer.